# Jmeter not showing JSON response

Tags: json, api, jmeter

I am not sure, if I am missing something but unable to find on google as well.
I am looking into some features of Jmeter. I used postman as well.
We have API POST request and it returns JSON response.

While hitting my API from Postman, I am getting 'JSON' response. (i.e. no issues) and API triggers my service.

Now, if hit from Jmeter. Response if 200 and my service trigger too. But in response I am getting some code or key rather JSON values.

Like 'e5e9e97a9ba2144b448c8b150498b5a0'.

```
Sample HTTP Request:
Thread Name: First_API_Test 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-03-28 15:48:33 IST
Load time: 7608
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 7608
Size in bytes: 492
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 127
Body size in bytes: 365
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 200
Response message: HTTP/1.1 200


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

- I tried changing HTTP Header Manager, but no luck.
- I tried 'View Result Tree' JSON drop-down, but that was my bad to try because that will work once I get response. I am not getting response at all.
- I search google and stackoverflow, but for JSON, everyone talking about handling/validating JSON response using JSON Extractor but for me I am getting JSON response at all.
- I tried to store the output but here too I am getting this code stored in generated output file.

```
....
</requestHeader>
  <responseData class="java.lang.String">e5e9e97a9ba2144b448c8b150498b5a0</responseData>
  <responseFile class="java.lang.String"></responseFile>
  <cookies class="java.lang.String"></cookies>
...
```

Expected result from Postman is:

```
{
    "outgoingFileId": "25808",
    "status": "Generated",
    "createdDate": NA,
    "reconcileStatus": null,
    "failureMessage": NA,
    "successMessage": NA,
    "executionTS": 1552912975190,
    "nextPayload": "{\"presentTS\":1553696530996,\"lastExecution\":1552912975190}"
}
```

Comment: Have you selected `Content-Type: application/json` in HTTP Head Manager ?

Comment: Yes: Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 3):

This is caused because in Advanced tab of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)  `Save response as MD5 hash?` is **checked** (you want to uncheck it)

[image]

> **Save response as MD5 hash?** If this is selected, then the response is not stored in the sample result. Instead, the 32 character MD5 hash of the data is calculated and stored instead. This is intended for testing large amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think. I missed. I was using latest version 5.1.1.r1855137
Under Http request by default option 'Save response MD5 Hash?' was checked. 
'un-check' resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was OP's issue, but I had an issue seeing response JSON because I had the dropdown above the request list in my results tree set to "Text". If I change it to "JSON" I can see the results.